# Get RANDOM ids with es query with node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

could anyone help me? Im new in elasticSearch and node.js.

**REQUEST**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next){
try {
    client.search({
        index: 'dbcatalogo',
        type: 'cars',
        size: 10,
        body: {
            query: {
                function_score:{
                    functions:[{
                        random_score:{
                            seed: 1
                        }
                    }]
                },
                match_all: {}
            },
            sort: {
                'AnoModelo': 'desc'
            }
        }
    }).then(function (json) {               
        res.json(json.hits);
    }, 
    function (err) {res.json(error.HandleError(err));});
}
catch (err) { res.json(error.HandleError(err)); }});
```

**RESPONSE**

[parse_exception] failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there the `match_all` needs to be within the query object of `function_score` as shows in function score below .

**Example:**

```
client.search({
    index: 'dbcatalogo',
    type: 'cars',
    size: 10,
    body: {
        query: {
            function_score:{
                functions:[{
                    random_score:{
                        seed: 1
                    }
                }],
                query : {
                    match_all: {}
            }
        }
        },
        sort: {
            'AnoModelo': 'desc'
        }
    }
}).then(function (json) {
    res.json(json.hits);
}
```

Also if you are sorting on a field other than [score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_track_scores) the `random_score` does not make much sense.